# What was the source of Kyra's powers?

Tags: the-bureau-of-magical-things

At the beginning of *The Bureau of Magical Things*, Kyra has an incident which seemingly gives her some measure of magical powers. Later, she is revealed to have orb magic: it is unclear precisely what this entails, but its main feature seems to involve using magic remotely. However, there are multiple affirmations throughout the series about the origin of her powers:

- First, Professor Maxwell suggests that it is the *residue* of the orb magic from the orb box that gave Kyra her powers.
- Then, he suggests that the conditions at the beginning of the first episode with the book replicated the conditions involved in the orb's creation, giving her orb magic.
- Except that the orb is revealed to have been hidden within the book in any case, so....
- To complicate things still further, in episode 17, he says something along the lines of "even if they take your orb powers, you'll still have your other powers," which appears to be correct, suggesting that the two are separate, and that the powers that she acquired at the beginning were *not* orb magic. However, the orb magic is described as being a combination of elf and fairy magic, just like the powers that Kyra acquired at the beginning of the show.
- To finish off the confusion, in the last episode, Kyra says that she lost her orb magic, with Professor Maxwell later saying that she has her orb magic permanently and her neither contradicting nor questioning him!

What actually gave Kyra her powers? Does she have two sets of powers from two different sources, and if so, which one gave her the orb magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, she was born a Tri-ling and acquired the orb magic through some type of contact with the orb.

It is unclear whether this clarifies the confusion in the first season, but the second season reveals (or retcons?) a few things that cast a different light on the matter:

- First, it is revealed that there are other Tri-lings, who are naturally born (presumably having fairy, elf, and human descent), and that Kyra was in fact born a Tri-ling. This is due to her birth father (whom I don't recall being mentioned in the first season) being one.
- In connection with this, Professor Maxwell said that his previous assumption, that the event with the book had been the cause of Kyra's baseline powers (being a Tri-ling), had been reasonable but clearly incorrect in light of the evidence. As such, we can probably take anything that Maxwell says or said about Kyra's powers as informed speculation at best, and thus susceptible to being wrong.
- In particular, Maxwell's initial guess that the event in the first episode replicated the conditions involved in the orb's formation seems to have been just that: a guess.
- That said, along similar lines, Maxwell posits that Kyra having been a Tri-ling made it easier for her to acquire orb magic, thus suggesting that there was a connection between the two, even though they were distinct. This would make sense, since the orb was described as having been created by elf and fairy magic in the first place.
  It is still unclear to me when precisely Kyra acquired orb magic, though.